# How to fix "the kernel failed to start due to the missing module 'prompt_toolkit.formatted_text'." in visual studio code

Tags: prompt-toolkit

I keep getting this error

> The kernel failed to start due to the missing module 'prompt_toolkit.formatted_text'. Consider installing this module

on anaconda navigator i have prompt_toolkit 3.0.2.0 installed

i tried to upgrade but the error kept coming up